# AnimatedVectorDrawable in Support Library and animation of "pathData"

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I am using **animated vectors** from **Support Library 23.2.0**, like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.0'
```

I am trying to animate "**pathData**" (morphing lines one to another). My code looks like this.

drawable/ic_done.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:name="tick"
        android:pathData="M4.8,12L9,16.2L20,8"
        android:strokeColor="#FF000000" />
</vector>
```

drawable/ic_done_animated.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_done">
    <target
        android:name="tick"
        android:animation="@animator/tick_path_animation" />
</animated-vector>
```

animator/tick_path_animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M4.8,12L4.8,12L4.8,12"
        android:valueTo="M4.8,12L9,16.2L9,16.2"
        android:valueType="pathType" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M4.8,12L9,16.2L9,16.2"
        android:valueTo="M4.8,12L9,16.2L20,8"
        android:valueType="pathType" />
</set>
```

Java code:

```
ImageView vImgAnimated = findByViewId(R.id.img);
AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animatedVector = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_done_animated);
vImgAnimated.setImageDrawable(animatedVector);
animatedVector.start();
```

It works well on newer device with **API level 21** but I have a problem on device with **API level 16**:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "M4.8,12L4.8,12L4.8,12"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:258)
    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadObjectAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:161)
    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:117)
    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:126)
    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:93)
    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:72)
    at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:377)
    at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:162)
    at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:142)
```

According to an article [android-support-library-232](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) the animated vectors (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) should be supported back to **API level 11**.

It looks like it fails while reading **valueFrom** attribute from **tick_path_animation.xml**. This attribute type "pathType" is probably not supported (yet?). Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: try to use Vector-Compat by wnafee https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat, I have tested path morphing, works well

Comment: Your question is solved in support lib 25.4.0+: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-4-0

Comment: For Path Morphing on platforms < API 21, you can use the Rich Path Animator https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorry, this will not work with the current version of the Support Library(23.2.0).

See [Chris Banes article](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.6g01n9fhl).

> There are also some limitations to what kind of things animated vectors can do when running on platforms < API 21. The following are the things which do not work currently on those platforms:
>
> Path Morphing (PathType evaluator). This is used for morphing one path into another path.
>
> Path Interpolation. This is used to defined a flexible interpolator (represented as a path) instead of the system defined ones like LinearInterpolator.
>
> Move along path. This is rarely used. The geometry object can move around, along an arbitrary path.

So animating the pathData, or 'Path Morphing' isn't currently supported.

**Update:**
Frank's comment:

> This is finally fixed in support lib 25.4.0 (June 2017): "Path
>   morphing and path interpolation are supported in
>   AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't able to find these limitations.

Comment: @Lewis McGeary: do you find any information of which version supports path

Comment: still doesn't work in 24.2.0 . It kind of renders the whole 'Compat' part of the Support library useless for me!  Quite annoying after stating compatibility back to API11, but hide the 'relevant' details of what doesn't work though. Should be called AnimatedVectorDrawablePartiallyCompat ..

Comment: @MarkKeen look at the comment above

Comment: This is because the support library currently relies on the framework's AnimatorInflater for vector drawables and the ability to declare a valueType other than intType or floatType for an objectAnimator has only been added in API 21. Even the documentation about animation resources is not up-to-date in this regard.

Comment: This is finally fixed in support lib 25.4.0 (June 2017): "Path morphing and path interpolation are supported in AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat"

Answer (score 4):

[image: API 16 animation]
the circular "flash" in the above animation  (in the center of the image) is me pressing the screen to start the morph.
**Inflating Drawable's**

`` `VectorDrawable` `` and `` `AnimatedVectorDrawable` `` in this support library (`vector-compat`) can be inflated in this way:

- Calling static `getDrawable()` methods:

```
//This will only inflate a drawable with <vector> as the root element
VectorDrawable.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_arrow_vector);

//This will only inflate a drawable with <animated-vector> as the root element
AnimatedVectorDrawable.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_arrow_to_menu_animated_vector);

// This will inflate any drawable and will auto-fallback to the lollipop implementation on api 21+ devices
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.any_drawable);
```

*If inflating the Drawable in java code, it is recommended to always use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()` as this handles Lollipop fallback when applicable. This allows the system to cache Drawable ConstantState and hence is more efficient.*
The library (`vector-compat`) has the following morph (bi-directional) animations :

Play-Pause morph animation

Play-Stop morph animation

Arrow-Hamburger menu morph animation

As you can see, I produced the above image on my `API 16` phone:

```
import com.wnafee.vector.compat.AnimatedVectorDrawable;
mdrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) AnimatedVectorDrawable.getDrawable(this.getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.consolidated_animated_vector);
```

Look at the github **README** for `vector-compat` here: https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat
This will fix your problem (down to `API 14`) if you merge it with your app module's `build.gradle` `dependencies` (usually at the end of file):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//Trying to FIX Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag animated-vector
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
//not needed
//  compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'//*******holy grail *******https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat
//  Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
//not needed
//  compile 'com.android.support:support-animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
}
```