# Animate Fab Button cross to mark

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

In my Android application I want to have a Floating Action Button to display a success state. I would like to have something like in the picture below:

[image]

But I have no idea how to animate the cross to the mark. Can someone please explain to me how I can do that? Is there maybe a library or something like that? Atm I'm using the default FAB from the design library.

Comment: I'd recommend looking up [AnimatedVectorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html), I think this will be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question got me interested in checking out `AnimatedVectorDrawable`, so I went ahead and made a small sample app that will achieve a similar animation, on github [here](https://github.com/alex-townsend/AnimatedVectorDrawableExample).

[Bad quality gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZOwC.gif).

Couple things to note: minimum SDK is set to 23 to make use of `AnimationCallbacks` for starting the 2nd animation, but you can achieve the same result using a `Handler.postDelayed()` with your animation durations to handle the drawable change and animation start. Since `AnimatedDrawableCompat` [does not support path morphing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806538/animatedvectordrawable-in-support-library-and-animation-of-pathdata), I needed two drawables to get the two different images.

Should be compatible with the Support Library `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` if you choose to use it as well.

Comment: Wow thank you that works great! I tried it also with `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` and it works wonderful on pre Lollipop devices. Great work!