# animated-vector-drawable API 16

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to use com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1, com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1 for API 16.
[Article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), I use Gradle Plugin 1.5.
In API 23 it's works fine but for API 16 I have some errors:

```
04-10 12:32:24.097: E/dalvikvm(1039): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable', referenced from method android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.isRunning
04-10 12:32:24.097: E/dalvikvm(1039): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable', referenced from method android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.start
04-10 12:32:24.097: E/dalvikvm(1039): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable', referenced from method android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.stop
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039): Exception while inflating <animated-vector>
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0   -70,70z"
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:258)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadObjectAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:161)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:117)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:126)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:93)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:72)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:377)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:162)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$AvdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:865)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:320)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:49)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:65)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at s99.vectoranimationtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AvdcInflateDelegate(1039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{s99.vectoranimationtest/s99.vectoranimationtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class ImageView
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class ImageView
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at s99.vectoranimationtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     ... 11 more
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/avd.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004b
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1918)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:55)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:391)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:49)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:65)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     ... 21 more
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag animated-vector
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1915)
04-10 12:32:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     ... 36 more
```

ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/avd"/>
```

avd.xml:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vectordrawable"
    tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <target
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:animation="@anim/rotation" />
    <target
        android:name="v"
        android:animation="@anim/path_morph" />
</animated-vector>
```

vectordrawable.xml:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="64dp"
    android:width="64dp"
    android:viewportHeight="600"
    android:viewportWidth="600" >
    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:pivotX="300.0"
        android:pivotY="300.0"
        android:rotation="45.0" >
        <path
            android:name="v"
            android:fillColor="#000000"
            android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

rotation.xml:

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="6000"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="360" />
```

path_morph.xml:

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0   -70,70z"
        android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
        android:valueType="pathType"/>
</set>
```

start animation:

```
ImageView textView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
Drawable drawable = textView.getDrawable();
if (drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) {
    ((AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) drawable).start();
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "s99.vectoranimationtest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: give your vector gradle configuration code

Comment: I have added this code:
 // Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 } // but have errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AnimatedVectorDrawable in Support Library and animation of "pathData"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806538/animatedvectordrawable-in-support-library-and-animation-of-pathdata)