# Pre Lollipop cannot play AnimatedVectorDrawable when app use Proguard

Tags: java, android

Since Google give out the Support 23.2.1 , I start use VectorDrawable in my Project.
At first,just use for TEST , no proguard , it works fine , show and played fine.

But when we plan to build and publish app, we use

```
minifyEnabled true and            
proguardFile file('proguard-rules.txt')
```

in gradle file, then ,it cannot played any more.

My Play Method:

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) {
        if (((AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) drawable).isRunning()) {
            ((AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) drawable).start();
        }
    }
```

The error:

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable', referenced from method android.support.b.a.b.isRunning
>    E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable', referenced from method android.support.b.a.b.start
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable', referenced from method android.support.b.a.b.stop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806538/animatedvectordrawable-in-support-library-and-animation-of-pathdata

Comment: My problem is not about path morphing. My thing is: why proguard will let animation not play pre lolipop? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your proguard config:

```
-keep class android.support.graphics.drawable.** { *; }
```

I found this by looking at the build/outputs/mapping/release/usage.txt which lists the classes proguard has removed. Tested on Android 4.4 and 5.1.

Comment: Life Saver. Had an app release today, and your answer helped me. Thanks @mark