# vector drawable crashes on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, vector, android-drawable

I found there were numerous vector drawable crashes happened on pre-Lollipop devices and I can’t reproduce it.

One is caused by **org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector** when I use `setImageResource`

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_mylib_offline_tracks_32.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020414
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2141)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:711)
        at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.superGetDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:433)
        at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.getDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:67)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:360)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
...
```

Code:

```
@override
protected void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    ...    
    viewHoler.imageView.setImageResource(vectorResId);
    ...
}
```

Vector drawable - **ic_mylib_offline_tracks_32.xml**:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="32.0"
    android:viewportWidth="32.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M7,21v3.75c0,0.69 0.54,1.25 1.2,1.25h15.6c0.66,0 1.2,-0.56 1.2,-1.25V21M19,17l-3,2 -3,-2M16,6v12"
        android:strokeColor="#A0A098" android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

And the others caused by **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_more_white_24.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020357. If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.** when I refresh toolbar menu visibility.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_more_white_24.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020357. If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
        at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.superGetDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:435)
        at android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources.getDrawable(VectorEnabledTintResources.java:67)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:125)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:210)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:187)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:196)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:476)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1164)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:291)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1051)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemVisibleChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1090)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setVisible(MenuItemImpl.java:651)
...
```

Code:

```
public void refreshMenuItemVisibility(boolean visibility) {
    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_overflow).setVisible(visible);
}
```

Vector drawable - **ic_more_white_24.xml**:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="32dp"
    android:height="32dp"
    android:viewportWidth="32.0"
    android:viewportHeight="32.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M10.5,16.5m-1.5,0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,3 0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,-3 0"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M16.5,16.5m-1.5,0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,3 0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,-3 0"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M22.5,16.5m-1.5,0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,3 0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,-3 0"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector>
```

I have already followed the step from the official document, but it doesn't work.

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

My library and tools version are as follow:

- Android Support Library: 26.0.0
- Build Tools: 26.0.0
- Gradle: 3.3
- Android Plugin: 2.3.3

#### UPDATE

All of the vectors are put in `drawable` folder.

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806538/animatedvectordrawable-in-support-library-and-animation-of-pathdata/41409624#41409624)

Comment: where is ic_more_white_24.xml file please show it.

Comment: @Han.... does my answer helped you or not?

Comment: @krishankTripathi Sorry I forgot to write down the file name of these two vectors. And now you can see it.

Comment: I do have the exact same problem. Spent a few hours on stackoverflow without success so far. I'm thinking maybe this happens if the device is super low on memory. The support lib fails to decode the vector xml and fallbacks to the native decode which fails with an exception. Really just a wild guess but I have no clue what else could be going on.

Answer (score 4):

Try this and see if working or not.

For me its working as i am using support library 23.4.0:

Add this to build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Add the following to onCreate of your Application class

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

For all xml views in which you are setting a vector drawable replace

```
android:src
```

with

```
app:srcCompat
```

and in the code replace this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(...);
```

with

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(...);
```

Comment: if you still find issues go to this link https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of things you need to fix.

1) First put your vector image in `drawable` folder instead of `drawable-v24.`

2) Also add support for `vector drawables` in `gradle` file.

```
android {
     defaultConfig {

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

3) There is also a work around for this. Make a resource file in your drawable folder and do something like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Vector drawable"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, all of the vectors are put in `drawable` folder. And I have added the `support` in gradle and the `layer-list` wrapper, but it didn't work.